# Swiper inicialization

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I have problem with JQuery slider "Swiper" (API here - http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php ).
I need scroll Swiper to some "slide" when I load page. => I used function "mySwiper.swipeTo" to scroll Swiper. This works fine in function "onSlideClick", but when I add similiar code to function "onFirstInit" or "onInit" or "onSwiperCreated" then nothing work (only error). It is look like Swiper don´t know what is "mySwiper" => using codes like "mySwiper.slides.length" make error and Swiper not work.

Code example of incicialization Swiper:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
      mode:'vertical',
      slidesPerView: 5,
      grabCursor: true,
      loop: false,
          onFirstInit: function() {
            zmena_obsahu_load();
          },
          onSlideClick: function() {
            zmena_obsahu_klik();
          }
    });

    var zmena_obsahu_load = function() {
      var index_lo = $(".menu_aktivni_trida").attr("data-id");

      var pocet_slidu = mySwiper.slides.length;
      if( (index_lo-2) <= 0 ){
        mySwiper.swipeTo((index_lo), '500', false);
      }
      else{
        mySwiper.swipeTo((index_lo-2), '500', false);        
      }

    };

    var zmena_obsahu_klik = function() {
      var index_slidu = $(mySwiper.clickedSlide).attr("data-id");
      var index_slidu2 = mySwiper.clickedSlideIndex;

      $(".obsah_posuv").hide();
      $("#posuv_"+index_slidu).show();
      $(".swiper-slide").removeClass("menu_aktivni_trida");
      $(mySwiper.clickedSlide).addClass("menu_aktivni_trida");

      var pocet_slidu = mySwiper.slides.length;
      if( (index_slidu2-2) <= 0 ){
        mySwiper.swipeTo((index_slidu2), '500', false);
      }
      else{
        mySwiper.swipeTo((index_slidu2-2), '500', false);        
      }

    };

    $('.posuv_menu_h').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      mySwiper.swipePrev()
    })
    $('.posuv_menu_d').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      mySwiper.swipeNext()
    })

  }
  </script>
```

This code write me: "TypeError: zmena_obsahu_load is not a function" but "zmena_obsahu_klik" is ok.

My function "zmena_obsahu_klik" work fine => ignore this function there is no problem and for that and not write for what I used it.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Now I used "Swiper Hash Navigation" (http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/plugins/hashnav.php#slide3). It seem like solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have soluton of this problem. =>
"Swiper Hash Navigation" (idangero.us/sliders/swiper/plugins/hashnav.php#slide3)

Not ideal solution but works and I rewrite code of this script to work without ugly hash on url =>

line `var hash = document.location.hash.replace('#', '');`
a change to `var hash = document.getElementById("akt_rok").textContent;`

and span with id "akt_roke" have "display: none" => It works without hash in url.